# Variables when running PowerShell on cmd line vs ISE

Tags: powershell, variables, scope

This is a block of the code I am using in PowerShell - it works perfectly well when run in the ISE, however when called from the command line it loses the value of some of the fields in the `Write-Output` command:

```
$csvfile | Group-Object "Employee ID" | ForEach-Object {
    $first_line = "Y"
    $EmployeeID = ($_.Group.'Employee ID' | Select -First 1)
    if ($_.Group.'Employee ID' -ne "Employee ID") {
        $date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"
        $DateStr = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f $date
        if ($first_line = "Y") {
            $Sum = ($_.Group | Measure-Object 'Journal Amount' -Sum).Sum
            $TaxSum = (($_.Group | Measure-Object 'Report Entry Total Reclaim Adjusted Amount' -Sum).Sum / 2)
            $SumMinusTax = $Sum - $TaxSum
            $myoutput = "E;{8};INV;;{3};{2};PLE;4;{4};{6};{2};{3};GB01NETBACS;Expenses;GBP;;DMG;;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;{7};{9}" -f $_.Name, $EmployeeID , $Item.'Employee ID', $DateStr, $Item.'Report Name', ";", $DateStr, $SumMinusTax, $Item.'Branch', $TaxSum
            write-output $myoutput | out-file -filepath $outputfile -append -encoding ASCII
            $first_line = "N"
        }
    }
}
```

The fields that lose the values are any of the ones with the specified field name in them, `$Item.'Report Name'` for example. Calculated values like `$TaxSum` are fine.

I have been trying to find the answer - tried making these global variables, but nothing seems to get these values output...

Any ideas?

---

To elaborate a little on this (thanks for the ideas):

Thanks for the ideas - I'm probably missing something very obvious ... I tried the `$Item = $_.group` - but that didn't work for the ISE run - I got `System.Object[]` in place of the field I wanted. Here's the full code (aside from the header variables with servers/passwords, etc.:

[code]$outputfile=$files.Fullname + ".output"

```
$csvfile=import-csv $files
$csvfile | group-object "Employee ID" |
ForEach-Object
{
    $first_line="Y"
    $EmployeeID = ($_.Group.'Employee ID' | Select -First 1)
    if ($_.Group.'Employee ID' -ne "Employee ID")
    {
        write-host "Emp ID : " $EmployeeID
        $date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"
        $DateStr = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f $date
        if ($first_line="Y")
        {
            $Sum = ($_.Group | Measure-Object 'Journal Amount' -Sum).Sum
            $TaxSum = (($_.Group | Measure-Object 'Report Entry Total Reclaim Adjusted Amount' -Sum).Sum /2)
            $SumMinusTax=$Sum - $TaxSum
            $datestr_report='{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f $Item.'Batch Date'
            $myoutput="E;{8};INV;;{3};{2};PLE;4;{4};{6};{2};{3};GB01NETBACS;Expenses;GBP;;DMG;;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;{7};{9}" -f $_.Name, $EmployeeID , $Item.'Employee ID', $DateStr,  $Item.'Report Name', ";", $DateStr, $SumMinusTax,$Item.'Branch',$TaxSum #";" $Sum #$date
            write-output $myoutput | out-file -filepath $outputfile -append -encoding ASCII
            $first_line="N"
        }
        ForEach ($Item in $_.Group )
        {
            $Item = $_.Group
            if ($item.'Journal Account Code' -ne '')
            {
                $tax_line_det="Detail Tax Line : {0}" -f $Item.'Report Entry Total Reclaim Adjusted Amount'
                $taxcode_det="GBNIL"
                if ($Item.'Report Entry Total Reclaim Adjusted Amount' -gt 0)
                {
                    $taxcode_det="GB001"
                }
                if ($item.'Journal Account Code' -eq "OHVEHFUEL")
                {
                     $veh="ZNA"
                }
                $myoutput_detail="L;5;;0;0;{2};{1};UN;1;{3};{3};0;0;0;;;{4};" -f $Item.'Employee ID',$Item.'Report Entry Description', $item.'Journal Account Code',  $item.'Journal Amount', $taxcode_det
                $myoutput_detail_lc="LC;18L;;;;;BRN;PRD;EMP;VEH;{0};;{1};{4}" -f $Item.'Branch', $Item.'Employee ID', $Item.'Report Entry Total Reclaim Adjusted Amount',$taxcode_det, $veh
            }
        }

        # Now need to append the Tax Lines
        $tax_line2=($_.Group | Measure-Object 'Report Entry Tax Reclaim Transaction Amount' -Sum).Sum
        write-host "Tax Line 2 : " $tax_line2
        if ($tax_line2 -gt 0)
        {
            $tax_line1="T;GB001;" + ($_.Group | Measure-Object 'Report Entry Tax Reclaim Transaction Amount' -Sum).Sum
        }
        if ($tax_line2 = 0)
        {
            $tax_line1="T;GBNIL;" + ($_.Group | Measure-Object 'Report Entry Tax Reclaim Transaction Amount' -Sum).Sum
        }
        write-output $tax_line1 | out-file -filepath $outputfile -append -encoding ASCII
}
# Now need to move the file into a 'processed' area
Move-Item $files $processed_dir
Move-Item $outputfile $import_dir[/code]
```

Is there something in that causing my cmd line call to forget certain fields?

Comment: In your ISE session, somewhere you've set a value for `$Item`.  That variable `$Item` doesn't have a value by default, so you'll need to set it in this script as well.  However, it's possible you meant to use `$PSItem` which can be used to reference the current object in a `ForEach` loop instead of `$_`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea - just tried with $PSItem instead, but the same results (works in ISE, not when called from cmd line)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your command line calling of the script?

Comment: Of course - just a simple .bat file with this in : Powershell.exe -File  D:\<Mypath>\Import.ps1

Comment: Something is different between the variables in your ISE session vs. your console session. Close the ISE and run again and you will probably see the same problem you are seeing in your console session.

Comment: Just tried that Bill ... same result - ISE outputs the variables and the command line call doesn't

Comment: I can't reproduce it. There is something in your environment that is different. You will need to write an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and post it along with example input data. In so doing you will probably identify the problem.

Comment: In the ISE, run this cmd `psedit $PROFILE`, and then search that for `$item`.  If you don't see it specified there, then something you're not mentioning creates that value.

Comment: Try to execute `$Item = $_.Group` before the first usage of the `$Item` variable in the script block of the `-Process` parameter of the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet.

Comment: Hi Bill/FoxDeploy - i've not managed to get your suggestions to work - so I guess i'm missing something (so I have added the full code, bar the variable declarations in the header, to see if you might be able to spot my error)